# PHP Remote Debugging doesnt trigger when the ServerName varies

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, debugging

I am remote debugging a PHP project (Wordpress plugin) that runs on a Docker container.
I am debugging with Intellij. Intellij listens on 9000.  The container runs the wordpress instance on port 80 but that port is forwarded to the host which maps it to 8081.  The host is a windows 11 machine - the mapping is mainly due to the fact that its generally a PITA to map ports below 1000 on windows machines.

The Wordpress instance was accessed by calling http://localhost:8081/ from the host machine and debugging would trigger perfectly.

I then realized the wordpress instance itself was struggling - it was unable to make api calls back on itself to trigger its cron jobs - the way wordpress appears to trigger its cronjobs is to curl `http://{site_host}:{site_port}/wp-cron`.  Obviously in the wordpress settings I had the site host as localhost.  and port as 8080. Locally the port is 80 hence why the loop was falling - so I updated the site name to 'host.docker.internal'  Which is an alias for the host machine.  The site worked perfercty loopbacks triggered appropriately and site health issues relating to the rest api resolved.

However now my debugger never gets triggered.

If I force my machine to access http://localhost:8080/some-path - it works until wordpress's url rewriter switches me back to host.docker.interal.

I cant work out why this happens.  Any ideas. To be clear I understand why the rewriter is switching me back to host.docker.internal - thats the site-host I updated in the Wordpress config.

The php debug config is

```
    [xdebug]
    xdebug.mode=develop,debug
    xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
    xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

My question is why the debugger doesnt trigger when the site is accessed at host.docker.internal?